# angularjs $resource using JSONP

Tags: angularjs, resources, jsonp

Recently, I have the problem to retrieve data from other server by using JSONP. I use the ng-resource of angularjs in the front-end, and it return the error response 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'.

I have tried many solutions in stack overflow, such as add the '{callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}', but the error still exist. So I really hope someone can help me to deal with this situation! Many thanks!

Here are part of my code:

```
SearchModule.factory('SearchService', function(SEARCH_API, $resource) {
    return {
        translate: function() {
            return $resource(SEARCH_API.mt, {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
                    {'transTar':  {method: 'JSONP', 
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        }}});
        }
    }
})
```

the following code is using the $resource to get the data

```
SearchService.translate().transTar({'text':'how are you'}).$promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: when I use Jquery, this will work. I have compared with their response, and I found that the result is nested by Jquery.callback, so Jquery can parse the result correctly. But when using angularjs, the result is not nested by 'angular.callbacks._0 ()', so it returns the error  'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'. Therefore, my question is how this happened and how to solve it? Thanks!